# Creating an integral from 2 functions

Tags: integration

Let $R$ be the region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ below the line $y = x + 2$ and above the parabola $y = x^2$. Check the integral of these $2$ functions in terms of $dx\cdot dy$ and then $dy\cdot dx$
'
I am having an issue figuring out what the integrals will range from. I have:
$$G =\{(y,x) : -1 < x < 2 \text{ and } x^2 < y < (x + 2)\}\to dy.dx$$
$$H =\{(x,y) :  0 < y < 4 \text{ and } y -2 < x < \sqrt{y}\} \to dx.dy$$

However when I create the integrals in terms of $dx\cdot dy$ and $dy\cdot dx$ they differ? Any help please, did i get the range of the $G$ and $H$ wrong? Its a parabola cut with a line

Answer (score 1):

For the region $H$, the lower limit of $x$ shouldn't be $y-2$.

It should be the maximum of $-\sqrt{y}$ and $y-2$. In fact, when $0 \le  y \le 1$, the lower limit is $-\sqrt{y}$.

That is

$$H =\{(x,y):  0 \le y \le 4 , \max(-\sqrt{y}, y-2) < x < \sqrt{y} \} $$

That is from the picture below, the left limit of the region consists of the green color and blue color part.

[image]

Comment: I originally wrote an answer for the duplicate, so I copied it here. (+1) btw

Comment: I did the same thing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

For $dydx$ the integral over $1$ is given by
$$\int_{-1}^2\int_{x^2}^{x+2}dydx=\int_{-1}^2-x^2+x+2dx=[\frac13x^3+\frac12x^2+2x]_{-1}^2=\frac92$$
with the region that you correctly evaluated. But for the second integral we need to split the region into two parts - for $0\le y\le1$ we have that $-\sqrt{y}\le x\le\sqrt{y}$ and when $1\le y\le4$ we have $y-2\le x\le\sqrt{y}$. So the integral over the function $1$ is
$$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^\sqrt{y}dxdy+\int_1^4\int_{y-2}^\sqrt{y}dxdy=\int_0^12\sqrt{y}\,dy+\int_1^4\sqrt{y}-y+2\,dy$$
$$=[\frac43y^{\frac32}]_0^1+[\frac23y^{\frac32}-\frac12y^2+2y]_1^4=\frac92$$
So the two regions are now equal.

Comment: Thank you this helps loads. My text book does not describe  splitting them up and i did not think of it. Much appreciated!